# Make a list item maintain fixed position on resize

Tags: html, css, layout

Suppose there's an unordered list inside a resizable `div` container, and that list is laid out horizontally and aligned to the right.
In that list one of the items is chosen as "special", say is assigned `id="pinned"`.

Is it possible by means of CSS only to make the `#pinned` item maintain its position relative to a containing `div` while that `div` is resized, so that other list items may change their position (float) around the `#pinned` item?

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. This code will only work if the pinned list item is the first in the list.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="pinned">item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    background: lightyellow;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
li {
    padding: 10px 50px;
    background: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
#pinned {
    float: right;
    background: lightgreen;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmw2gr26/)

Comment: Quite smart use of float.